# How to save multiple images in .mat file In MATLAB environment

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Below is my code that i have tried but it reads the images from the folder but when i am
trying to store the all image  to mat file but it store the last array in the mat file

```
myFolder = 'C:\Users\protocol\Desktop\Finger-Print';
if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
  baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  imageArray = imread(fullFileName);

  save db2.mat imageArray; here it save the last image array to db2.mat file

  imshow(imageArray);  % Display image.
  drawnow; % Force display to update immediately.
end
```

but but i want to store multiple images in a mat file so that i can load this file later
and access the images

Comment: You'll needed different variable names for each image, and you'll need to append `-append` when you save in the loop. I would recommend multiple files with the same variable name instead.

Comment: thanks for reply i have solve my problem below is the code posted

Answer (score 4):

You can store the images in a cell array, and then save the entire array into a mat file.

```
clear all; clc; addpath(genpath(pwd));
myFolder = 'C:\Users\protocol\Desktop\Finger-Print\Matlab\Simple_FingerPrint_Matching\FVC2002\DB2_B';
if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.tif');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);
 result = cell(1,100);
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
  baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  imageArray= imread(fullFileName);
  result{k} = imageArray;
end
save db2.mat result;
```